# How to add Spring Data Neo4j metadata to externally loaded data?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j 2.0.1, I have started to use the Cypher transactional REST endpoint to bulk load data into neo4j (this is very fast). I'd like the data loaded in this fashion to be indistinguishable from data created with the SDN API.

After some digging around I found that the following Cypher statement will add a bare minimum of such metadata such that the SDN API works after loading some `DomainObject`s via the REST endpoint:

```
match (d:DomainObject) set d:_DomainObject return count(d);
```

I also added this property to the `DomainObject` nodes:

`__type__ = DomainObject.class.getName()`

So my question is: what exactly is required in terms of metadata (for both nodes and relationships) for SDN to function correctly with externally loaded data?